# Conda environment's python segmentation fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, conda

I I'm trying to use python with conda environment.
I create an environment using

```
 conda create -n new_env3 python=3.9
```

Then when I start python terminal (just running 'python') I get:

> Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 06:56:58)
> [GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> Segmentation fault

I tried multiple python versions and sub-versions, but all resulted in the same error

Comment: Please add output of `conda list` to question body.

Answer (score 2):

i met the same problem, and `conda clean -a` didn't solve the problem

> $ python 
> Python 3.10.6 (main, Oct 24 2022, 16:07:47) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
> Segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

Try running `conda clean -a`.

This will remove all unused packages.

Answer (score 0):

Need to update version for GCC 4.9, make 4.0, GLIBC 2.26, solved these problems at Centos 7.9, by following operation to upgrade:

GCC 4.9:

```
yum install centos-release-scl
yum install devtoolset-9-gcc*
scl enable devtollset-9 bash
gcc -v
```

make 4.0

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-4.3.tar.gz
tar -xzvf make-4.3.tar.gz 
cd make-4.3/
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/make
make
make install
cd /usr/bin/
mv make make.bak # backup
ln -sv /usr/local/make/bin/make /usr/bin/make
make -v
```

GLIBC 2.26

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.25.tar.gz
tar -xzvf glibc-2.25.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.25
mkdir build && cd build
../configure --prefix=/usr --disable-profile --enable-add-ons --with-headers=/usr/include --with-binutils=/usr/bin
make
make install
strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC
```

My environment: Centos 7.9, Miniconda3, Python 3.10, Terminal

Answer (score 0):

Please check the output of `echo $LANG`, I have run into the same issue when `LANG=C.UTF-8`. I have no reason why it happens but it can be fixed by

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```